# How to avoid Ctrl-E execute accidents with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

SQL Server Management Studio executes the entire script after Ctrl-E is pressed.

For manual maintenance script files, I have been commenting out all UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE statements.

Execution is then only done by a selecting the SQL script to execute.

Are there other ways to avoid Ctrl-E execute accidents?

Comment: Sorry, SQL Server Query Analyser or SQL Server Management Studio?  QA is years deprecated, but is an actual product so I ask...

Comment: Pretty sure you mean SSMS and not query analyzer. How does one "accidentally" hit ctrl-e? You can also hit F5 which is a bit easier. Not really sure what your question is here though.

Comment: (I always gave a joke in my Bad Habits / Best Practices presentation that one way to avoid this is to have your New Query template have a `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` at the top, and commit and rollback commented out below, which would give you the opportunity to roll everything back if you made a booboo. But sometimes the joke would be on you, because you'd perform some update inside the transaction, then go to lunch or home for the night...

Comment: @squillman - You are right, I use SSMS (and used QA years ago). I have edited my question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `set noexec on;` at the top of your script. That will prevent running *any* statements in the file.

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: Thanks, Mando. :)

Comment: @JohnH It's the way ... until you forget to add that clause. That's why at our company, we've removed this shortcut in all critical environments. YMMV, as usual ;-).

Comment: @TT. - you're right. But with all due respect, it's turtles all the way down. That is, your solution needs to be applied to all SSMS installs in your org. So your admonishment of "it works until you forget to apply it" also applies to you.; there is no bulletproof solution.

Comment: @BenThul True. It's a procedure we stick to for each new installation in critical environments though. We prefer not to have our fingers burned in any case, hence our strategy. A lot more failure points, a few installations versus a ton of scripting and all that.

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server Management Studio you can remove the shortcut CTRL+E to execute a query.

Go to Tools > Options in the menu, then go to Environment > Keyboard > Keyboard in the tree on the left. Then select `Query.Execute` in the right table. Select the shortcut `CTRL+E (SQL Query Editor)` then click Remove which removes the shortcut. You will then no longer be able to execute the query when clicking CTRL+E.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To prevent executing an entire script file from start to end, and only allow running selected snippets, this would work:

```
WHILE 1=1
  PRINT 'NOT ALLOWED, press the STOP button'

PRINT 'After WHILE, will not show unless executed manually'

GO

PRINT 'After GO, will not show unless executed manually'
```

Because the server goes into *very busy loop*, it may not immediately stop when you click the STOP button, but it will stop in the end.

For sake of completeness, here is the **STOP** button:

> [image]